# Python TypeError unsupported operand type

Tags: python, typeerror

In Python,

`logging.info('Followers: %d ', sum([a[1] for a in total]))`, where `sum` is an integer and `total` is `list comprehension` of integers. I get this,

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` ?? Not sure, why ??

Comment: Is total a list of lists?  If not, you shouldn't be subscripting `a` in your list comprehension.  Can you provide a printout of `total`?  That would make the problem clear.

Comment: `sum` is not an integer; it's a function. `total` is not a list comprehension of integers; it's a list of lists.

Comment: @melpomene it's an iterable of iterables.

Comment: We need to know your actual `total` to know why your code isn't working. It clearly isn't the type you described ("list comprehension of integers"), because "list comprehension" isn't a type, and a list of integers would raise a `TypeError` trying to call `a[1]` on an integer. And if it were just a list of list of integers (or any other iterable of iterables of integers), it would work, as Ashwini Chaudhary showed. So either `logging.info(str(total))` right before this line and post the result here, or show us the code that generates it, and someone can tell you what you got wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The Error means `a[1]` returned from the list `total` is both `string` as well as `integers`.

for eg.

```
In [9]: lis=[1,'foo',3]

In [10]: sum(lis)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

for `[(123243, 3), (24532, 5)]` your code works fine :

```
In [17]: lis=[(123243, 3), (24532, 5)]

In [18]: 'Followers: %d '%sum([a[1] for a in lis])
Out[18]: 'Followers: 8 '
```

Comment: @acjohnson55 - so total is [(123243, 3), (24532, 5)] for example, there is no string...

Comment: lis may consist of strings only and still raise the same TypeError and message.

Comment: @KuriousMind print type(a[1]) to test your hypothesis

Comment: @KuriousMind for `[(123243, 3), (24532, 5)]`, your code should work fine.